# How to define HTML tag from a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to select a string from an array, assign it to a variable and have that variable be a placeholder tag in HTML. This is what I have so far

```html
    <form  action="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" method="GET">
        <input class="search" type="text" name="q" autofocus>
        <br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Go!">
    </form>
```

For my javascript, I have this

```js
        var items = ["Search in Peace", "Search with DuckDuckGo", "Honk It!", "Your Search is Safe With Me", "Don't Google It!", "Duck It!"];
        function random_item(items)
        {

        var searchterm = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

        document.getElementById("q").placeholder = searchterm;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<body onload="startTime()" onload="random_item(items)" background="backgroundimg.png">
```

Comment: Where is your function called?

Comment: My function is called on load within the body

Comment: There is no id in your input tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript is fine.

```
var items = ["Search in Peace", "Search with DuckDuckGo", "Honk It!", "Your Search is Safe With Me", "Don't Google It!", "Duck It!"];
function random_item(items){
    var searchterm = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
    document.getElementById("q").placeholder = searchterm;
}

function startTime(){}
```

But you need to add the "q" id to the text input, like so:

```
<input class="search" type="text" name="q" id="q" autofocus>
```

and unify your body onload calls into a single call, like so:

```
<body onload="startTime();random_item(items);" background="backgroundimg.png">
```

Here's a full working example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var items = ["Search in Peace", "Search with DuckDuckGo", "Honk It!", "Your Search is Safe With Me", "Don't Google It!", "Duck It!"];
            function random_item(items){
                var searchterm = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
                document.getElementById("q").placeholder = searchterm;
            }

            function startTime(){}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="startTime();random_item(items);" background="backgroundimg.png">
        <form  action="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" method="GET">
            <input class="search" type="text" name="q" id="q" autofocus>
            <br>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Go!">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace 'name'

```
<input class="search" type="text" name="q" autofocus>
```

To 'id' like:

```
<input class="search" type="text" id="q" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the element with id `q`

```
document.getElementById("q")
```

But your input does not have this id, tought it has the attribute name.

```
<input class="search" type="text" name="q" autofocus>
```

Change the query

```
document.getElementByName("q")
```

Or add the id

```
<input class="search" type="text" id="q" name="q" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` tag had `name="q"` but not `id="q"`

```js
let items = ["Search in Peace", "Search with DuckDuckGo", "Honk It!", "Your Search is Safe With Me", "Don't Google It!", "Duck It!"];

function random_item(items) {

  let searchterm = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  console.log(searchterm);

  document.getElementById("q").placeholder = searchterm;
}

random_item(items);
```

```css
input[type=text]{
   min-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" method="GET">
  <input id="q" class="search" type="text" name="q" autofocus>
  <br>
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you can't have more than one HTML attributes with the same name on the same element.

So, only the first of your `onload` attributes will work, the browser will ignore the rest.

Also, your input has a `name` of `q` instead of an `id`, so you'll have to add an ID in order to make `getElementsById` find it.

Ways to solve the former problem:

1. Use only one onload attribute:

   ```
   <body onload="startTime(); random_item(items)" background="backgroundimg.png">
   ```
2. Or, even better, use `addEventListener` instead of the inline event listeners:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('load',startTime)
   document.addEventListener('load',()=>random_items(items))
   ```
3. You can use `addEventListener` with the `DOMContentLoaded` event, which fires right after the page's DOM is ready, and doesn't wait for the page (including images, iframes, etc.) finish loading:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('load',startTime)
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>random_items(items))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

your input tag has no id attribute, which sometimes really makes sense.
Your selector searches for an id. If you want to select the input field by name just use document.querySelector('input[name="q"]').